# OpenSSL RSA for Windows. Backdoor?

Tags: ssl, openssl, rsa

I did 5 "RSA 2048" private keys with "Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1j Light" tool.
(http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).
The link was from https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

Creation string:

openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048

All certs have 4 equal fragments. Is it a backdoor or NSA marker?
I have a small rating and I can't post images directly, so look at this:

i.stack.imgur.com/oozVX.jpg

Answer (score 0):

All your keys have the same underlying ASN1 structure so you might find very same value coding for the DER encoding structure of RSA private key.

openssl asn1parse -in private_key.pem

```
0:d=0  hl=4 l=1189 cons: SEQUENCE          
4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :00
7:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim:  INTEGER           :   
268:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim:  INTEGER           :010001
273:d=1  hl=4 l= 256 prim:  INTEGER           :..
533:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim:  INTEGER           :..
665:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim:  INTEGER           :..
797:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim:  INTEGER           :...
929:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim: INTEGER           :..
1061:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim:  INTEGER           :...
```

And  65537 (Hexadecimal **010001**) is the commonly public exponent 'e' used as known as more secrue than weaker exponents, so you will find it in quite every key.

That  is a very good to compare your keys indeed.